# Unity проект 3d URP периодический вылетает!

Tags: unity3d, 3d

Я создал 3D (URP) Unity проект и он сразу появился с такими ошибками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1-ая ошибка:

```
FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException (System.Boolean overflow, System.String overflowResourceKey) (at <75633565436c42f0a6426b33f0132ade>:0)
System.Number.ParseInt32 (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles styles, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) (at <75633565436c42f0a6426b33f0132ade>:0)
System.Int32.Parse (System.String s) (at <75633565436c42f0a6426b33f0132ade>:0)
Unity.Burst.BurstCompilerOptionsInternal.DeserialiseStringArraySafe (System.String input) (at <a2dd15248a25411e914af2a2c82fb63f>:0)
Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitCompilerService.GetAssemblyPaths (System.String folders) (at <a2dd15248a25411e914af2a2c82fb63f>:0)
Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitCompilerService.EnsureLibraryCacheLoaded (System.String assemblyPaths) (at <a2dd15248a25411e914af2a2c82fb63f>:0)
Burst.Compiler.IL.Jit.JitCompilerService.CompileInternal (System.String fullMethodName, System.String assemblyPaths, System.IntPtr userdata, Unity.Burst.NativeDumpFlags dumpFlags, System.IntPtr compilerCallbackPointer, System.IntPtr logCallBack, System.String compilerFlags) (at <a2dd15248a25411e914af2a2c82fb63f>:0)
Unity.Burst.LowLevel.BurstCompilerService:GetDisassembly(MethodInfo, String)
Unity.Burst.BurstCompiler:SendRawCommandToCompiler(String)
Unity.Burst.CommandBuilder:SendToCompiler()
Unity.Burst.BurstCompiler:SendCommandToCompiler(String, String)
Unity.Burst.BurstCompiler:RequestSetProtocolVersion(Int32)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstLoader:.cctor()
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes(Type[])
```

2-ая ошибка:

```
Assertion failed on expression: 'exception == SCRIPTING_NULL'
UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility:ExtractStackTrace ()
Unity.Burst.BurstCompiler:SendRawCommandToCompiler (string) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/Runtime/BurstCompiler.cs:770)
Unity.Burst.BurstCompiler/CommandBuilder:SendToCompiler () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/Runtime/BurstCompiler.cs:97)
Unity.Burst.BurstCompiler:SendCommandToCompiler (string,string) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/Runtime/BurstCompiler.cs:784)
Unity.Burst.BurstCompiler:RequestSetProtocolVersion (int) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/Runtime/BurstCompiler.cs:653)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstLoader:.cctor () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/Runtime/Editor/BurstLoader.cs:213)
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes (System.Type[])
```

И они чередуются.

Я подумал что ничего страшного не будет. Проект ведь всё равно запускался но он  часто начал вылетать с такими ошибками:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Obtained 64 stack frames
0x00007fff4a71ad3c (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mono-hash.c:122] mono_g_hash_table_find_slot 
0x00007fff4a791154 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [reflection.c:491] mono_type_get_object_checked 
0x00007fff4a72cabe (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2280] mono_class_create_runtime_vtable 
0x00007fff4a834e20 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [method-to-ir.c:9027] mono_method_to_ir 
0x00007fff4a7e5580 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini.c:3492] mini_method_compile 
0x00007fff4a7e7127 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini.c:4086] mono_jit_compile_method_inner 
0x00007fff4a7edddc (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2700] mono_jit_compile_method_with_opt 
0x00007fff4a7ef828 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:3309] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007fff4a72e764 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3066] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007fff4a729810 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:563] mono_runtime_class_init_full 
0x00007fff4a8444c2 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [method-to-ir.c:9929] mono_method_to_ir 
0x00007fff4a7e5580 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini.c:3492] mini_method_compile 
0x00007fff4a7e7127 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini.c:4086] mono_jit_compile_method_inner 
0x00007fff4a7edddc (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2700] mono_jit_compile_method_with_opt 
0x00007fff4a7ef828 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:3309] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007fff4a72e764 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3066] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007fff4a72e8fc (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3113] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff6a0ddb394 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff6a0dbac34 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff6a0db586a (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke<bool>
0x00007ff6a0f01dd8 (Unity) Scripting::UnityEngine::DebugProxy::CallOverridenDebugHandler
0x00007ff6a0dbb2bc (Unity) Scripting::LogException
0x00007ff6a0dbac92 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff6a0772fd0 (Unity) BurstCompilerService::CompileAsync
0x00007ff6a0773d8a (Unity) BurstCompilerService::GetDisassembly
0x00007ff69ff6e174 (Unity) BurstCompilerService_CUSTOM_GetDisassembly
0x000002920e2595e5 ((<unknown>)) 
0x000002920e25947b ((<unknown>)) 
0x000002920e25bda3 ((<unknown>)) 
0x000002920e259303 ((<unknown>)) 
0x000002920e2587f3 ((<unknown>)) 
0x000002920e256acb ((<unknown>)) 
0x000002920e2575bd ((<unknown>)) 
0x00007fff4a7efeb4 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:3445] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007fff4a72e764 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3066] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007fff4a729810 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:563] mono_runtime_class_init_full 
0x00007fff4a696290 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [icall-def.h:751] ves_icall_System_Runtime_CompilerServices_RuntimeHelpers_RunClassConstructor_raw 
0x000002920e1e28ea ((<unknown>)) 
0x000002920e1e27db ((<unknown>)) 
0x000002920e1e163b ((<unknown>)) 
0x000002920e5faaa8 ((<unknown>)) 
0x00007fff4a7efeb4 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:3445] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007fff4a72e764 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3066] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007fff4a72e8fc (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3113] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff6a0ddb394 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff6a0dbac34 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff6a0db5845 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke<void>
0x00007ff6a0ef7df3 (Unity) Scripting::UnityEditor::EditorAssembliesProxy::ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes
0x00007ff6a0dafa8b (Unity) MonoManager::SetupLoadedEditorAssemblies
0x00007ff6a0da557d (Unity) MonoManager::EndReloadAssembly
0x00007ff6a0dad108 (Unity) MonoManager::ReloadAssembly
0x00007ff6a1cfb20d (Unity) Internal_ADB_Only_ReloadAllUsedAssemblies
0x00007ff6a21b98ea (Unity) ImportOutOfDateAssets
0x00007ff6a21c5763 (Unity) RefreshInternalV2
0x00007ff6a21cce1b (Unity) StopAssetImportingV2Internal
0x00007ff6a1cd6646 (Unity) EditorSceneManager::RestoreSceneBackups
0x00007ff6a19ded25 (Unity) PlayerLoopController::EnterPlayMode
0x00007ff6a19eeb87 (Unity) PlayerLoopController::SetIsPlaying
0x00007ff6a19f1032 (Unity) Application::TickTimer
0x00007ff6a1e46ada (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x00007ff6a1e4b3ab (Unity) WinMain
0x00007ff6a31fe78e (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007fff903355a0 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007fff9058485b (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

Я думаю это не связано с ассетами потому что ошибки появились до импортирования ассетов.

Я даже не знаю что делать... (Я ещё новичок)

Comment: проект уже стал вылетать сразу при запуске сцены. Не возможно использовать

Answer (score 0):

У меня эта проблема была из за русских символов в пути к проекту